# How determine correct checksum algorithm for this NFC Data?

Tags: crc

I maae a dump of a Mifare Classic, NXP, tag.

I can read some information without a problem, but if I write data in a block, I need to terminate the block with a checksum (CRC?, one byte).

I tried with this:

https://hub.zhovner.com/tools/nfc/

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

But it didn't work.

This are block samples:

> 000000000000000000000000000000**F5**
>
> F50000000000000000000000000000**00**
>
> 300000000000000000000000000000**96**
>
> 01E1CCE70900000000000000000000**62**

So, how determine the last byte (in bold)

Comment: Given this information, I can only *guess* that it's likely to be a linear combination of the bits/bytes. I can't see a way to objectively answer the question however. // Try reverse engineer the code used to compute the checksum, if possible.